# Replacing a text node by another in xml using python

Tags: python, xml

this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<raml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="raml21.xsd">
<cmData type="actual" scope="all" name="plan_file">
<header>
 <log dateTime="2011-05-18T04:05:02" action="created" /> 
</header>
<managedObject class="Fruit">
 <p name="Apple">100</p> 
 <p name="Mango">4</p> 
 <p name="Pear">99</p> 
 <p name="Jackfruit">67</p> 
 <p name="Strawberry">200</p> 
 <p name="Guava">100</p> 
 <p name="Banana">100</p> 
 <p name="Breadfruit">1500</p> 
 <p name="Musambi">100</p> 
</managedObject>
</cmData>
</raml>
```

What i need to do is that. i need to replace the text nodes(100,4,99) of a given attribute with another number(entered through the python shell during run-time).i need to change only one text node at a time(which is also entered through the shell). i need a seperate xml file with the changed value.

i wrote the python script which goes like this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import os.path

def new_value(parameter, parameter_value, target_dir, inputfile):    
    count = len(open(inputfile).readlines())

    dom = minidom.parse(inputfile)
    name = dom.getElementsByTagName('p')
    inFile = open(inputfile,'r')

    fullname = os.path.join(target_dir, "test" + str(parameter_value) + ".xml")
    outFile = open(fullname,'w')

    for i in range(count):
        content = inFile.readline()
        matchobj = re.search(parameter, content)

        if(matchobj):        
            newcontent = content.replace(name[2].firstChild.nodeValue, str(parameter_value))
            outFile.write(newcontent)

        else:
            outFile.write(content)
    outFile.close()


parameter = input("Enter the parameter: ")
target_dir = input("Enter the target directory: ")
input_file = input("Enter the input file: ")
parameter_value = input("Enter the value to replace: ")
new_value(parameter, parameter_value, target_dir, input_file)
```

here since i am using the expression,

```
newcontent = content.replace(name[2].firstChild.nodeValue, str(parameter_value))
```

this script is running but using this(since i am using name[2]), i can change only the index 2 of the xml file,ie, Pear.if i write 1 instead of 2, i am able to change the value of Mango and so on.
but i need to make the script general. how can i modify the script for that???

Thanks for ur help.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you're using Python 3 (`input()`) instead of Python 2 (`raw_input()`).

Why exactly are you trying to use regular expressions (the `re` module)? As I understand what you're trying to do, you're trying to parse an XML file into a DOM, find a `<p>` element identified by its `name` attribute, replace its text with user-supplied text, and write it out to a new file. You can do the replacing far more reliably by manipulating the DOM than by trying to run regular expressions on the raw XML stream. The following Python 3 program shows how to manipulate the DOM:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from xml.dom import minidom
import os.path

def new_value(parameter, parameter_value, target_dir, inputfile):
    # Load the XML file and parse it
    dom = minidom.parse(inputfile)

    # Find all <p> elements with the correct name= attribute
    els = [element
           for element in dom.getElementsByTagName('p')
           if element.getAttribute('name') == parameter]

    # Choose the first among these
    chosen_el = els[0]

    # Set its text content
    if chosen_el.hasChildNodes:
        # Assumes that the first child is in fact a text node
        chosen_el.firstChild.nodeValue = parameter_value
    else:
        # If the element is empty, add a child node
        chosen_el.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(parameter_value))

    fullname = os.path.join(target_dir, "test" + str(parameter_value) + ".xml")

    # Opening a file using a "with open" block automatically
    # closes it at the end of the block
    with open(fullname, 'wb') as outFile:
        outFile.write(dom.toxml('utf-8'))

parameter = input("Enter the parameter: ")              # or 'Mango'
target_dir = input("Enter the target directory: ")      # or '.'
input_file = input("Enter the input file: ")            # or 'so_xml.xml'
parameter_value = input("Enter the value to replace: ") # or 'Manstop'
new_value(parameter, parameter_value, target_dir, input_file)
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. but hen i mmodified my script and tried to execut, i got an error message 'EOL while scanning string literal' at this line 'for element in dom.getElementsByTagName('p')'

Comment: thank you so much for your help.. :)  it really worked..perfectly in the way i wanted.. thank you for spending the time to help me out :)